# Not being able to Insert data into MYSQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am trying to insert data into MySQL tables but I am not sure why it is not working

```
<?php
        include 'connect.php';
        $userName = $_POST['name']; 
        $firstname = $_POST['FirstName']; 
        $Surname = $_Post['Surname'];
        $email = $_POST['EmailAddress']; 
        $password = $_POST['Password']; 
        $gender = $_POST['Gender']; 
        $dob = $_POST['DOB'];
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `User` (`username`,`Password`,`First Name`,`Surname`, `Gender`, `DOB`, `Email Address`) 
                            VALUES ('.$userName.','.$password.','.$firstname.','.$Surname.', '.$gender.', '.$dob.', '.$email.')';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        try {
            $myarray = array(
                ":userName" => $userName,
                ":password" => $password,
                ":firstname" =>$firstname,
                ":Surname" => $Surname,
                ":gender" => $gender,
                ":dob" => $dob,
                ":email" => $email);
            print_r($myarray);
            $stmt->execute($myarray);
        } catch(PDOException $err) {
            echo "Houston we have a problem: $err";
        }
    ?>
```

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Prepared Statements wrong. With $db->prepare() you're actually submitting the query with **placeholders** and not with the values (called sending a template). In your case:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO `User` (`username`,`Password`,`First Name`,`Surname`, `Gender`, `DOB`, `Email Address`) 
                VALUES (:userName, :password, :firstname, :Surname, :gender, :dob, :email)';
```

Comment: I have tried that before but it is not workinggggg

Comment: "it's not working" is not an error message, post the error message you're get returned.

Comment: I did not get any error message. That s the problem..I added debug code print_r($myarray); and it printed whats in the execute PDO statement Array ( [:userName] => mfredy [:password] => Pulavan123 [:firstname] => Fareedh [:Surname] => [:gender] => M [:dob] => 23-10-1992 [:email] => fareedh92@hotmail.co.uk )

Comment: Did you set the PDO attribute PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION? http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Do I have to set that in the connecting to the database file?

Comment: Yes, after you're connecting to the database.

Comment: Open phpmyadmin and look what gets written in the table and make a comparison. If there is no error, the query should've been executed successfully. You could try using ? as placeholders and then numbers instead of `:userName`, `:password`and so on. Maybe you want to bind the values with `$stmt->bindvalue(number, $variable);` and not passing an array to `$stmt->execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

**First make sure you have connected to the sql properly then change your codes to this one:**

```
$table='User';
$sql="INSERT INTO
$table(username,Password,First Name,Surname,Gender,DOB,Email Address) VALUES ('$userName','$password','$firstname','$Surname', '$gender', '$dob', '$email')";

$result=$conn->query($sql) ;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: sorry I have changed some codes

Comment: First of all, tables or columns **have to be** in backticks if they're containing special characters, a reserved word or white spaces. Second thing, one does not simply use PDO without prepared statements. It's like saying hi to `'; DROP DATABASE;`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it seems to me ,probably we have some problems with connect.php isnt it?

Comment: I am using prepare statements.

Comment: I dont think so. It is connecting to the dtatabase properly. I checked the database name, user and password. It was all correct

Comment: @AminNasrEsfahani Dunno, he has to post the code of connect.php to make a proper diagnose.

Comment: <?php
    $host = 'mysql1.000webhost.com';
    $dbname = 'a7848759_lumos';
    $username = 'a7848759_fareedh';
    $password = 'Pulavan123';
 
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname'.$dbname,$username,$password);
    echo "ITS WORKING!!";
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}

?>

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I have suggested the below code whats your opinion ?

Comment: Well, if you get `ITS WORKING!!` you do have a connection. The question is what your actual problem is. Doesn't get the row inserted or something else wrong?

Comment: yhh the row is not being inserted..the connection is fine

Comment: can you take a picture from your database ?

Answer (score 0):

use this one for connection :

```
$db = "mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname";
$username = "  ";
$password = "  ";
$conn = new PDO( $db, $username, $password ) or die("Error Connection !! ");
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$userName = $_POST['name']; 
$firstname = $_POST['FirstName']; 
$Surname = $_Post['Surname'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress']; 
$password = $_POST['Password']; 
$gender = $_POST['Gender']; 
$dob = $_POST['DOB'];

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$query = 'INSERT INTO `User` (`username`,`Password`,`First Name`,`Surname`, `Gender`, `DOB`, `Email Address`) 
          VALUES (:userName, :password, :firstname, :Surname, :gender, :dob, :email)'
try {
    $stmt  = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute(array(
                        ":userName" => $userName,
                        ":password" => $password,
                        ":firstname" =>$firstname,
                        ":Surname" => $Surname,
                        ":gender" => $gender,
                        ":dob" => $dob,
                        ":email" => $email));
    if ($result) {
       // success!
       echo 'lastInsertId = '.$conn->lastInsertId(); 

    } else {
       // Query failed.
       echo 'errorcode = '.$stmt  ->errorCode();
    }
} catch(PDOException $err) {
        echo "Houston we have a problem: $err <br />";
        echo 'errorcode = '.$stmt  ->errorCode();
}
```